# Dynamic Euler–Bernoulli beam equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, physics

I am trying to solve for the vibration of a [Euler–Bernoulli beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory#Dynamic_beam_equation). The equation is

$\frac{\partial ^2u(t,x)}{\partial t^2}+\frac{\partial ^4u(t,x)}{\partial x^4}=0$

For the boundary conditions I would like the displacement to be zero at the ends and with zero second derivative. This corresponds to pinned-pinned conditions. For time I will start with a displacement and no velocity.

In the future I would like to solve for a beam that is not uniform in thickness along the x-axis and for general initial conditions.

There is a similar problem in the `NDEigensystem` documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html) but this is for the standard wave equation which is only second order in space. However, I follow that example. First I define an initial displacement and try to solve the pde.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := x (1 - x)

tu = NDSolveValue[{
    D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 4}] == 0,
    u[0, x] == f[x],
    Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0,
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 0, True],
    DirichletCondition[D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] == 0, True]
    }, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> "MethodOfLines"}];
```

This gives me the error

```
NDSolveValue::femcmsd: The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two.
```

Thus I proceed to supply two coupled differential equations one for displacement one for the second derivative (which is the bending moment). Thus I try to solve

```
tu = NDSolveValue[{
    D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] + D[m[t, x], {x, 2}] == 0,
    D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] == m[t, x],
    u[0, x] == f[x],
    Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0,
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 0, True],
    DirichletCondition[m[t, x] == 0, True]
    }, {u, m}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> "MethodOfLines"}];
```

However this also gives an error

```
NDSolveValue::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.
```

I don't understand this error because I think I have done as asked... Can you help? Thanks

Answer (score 69):

This post contains several code blocks, you can copy them easily with the help of [`importCode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3537/1871).

---

## Analytic Solution

The analytic solution can be obtained with `LaplaceTransform` and `FourierSinCoefficient`. First, make a Laplace transform on the equation and b.c.s and plug in the i.c.s:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] = x (1 - x);

eqn = D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 4}] == 0;
ic = {u[0, x] == f@x, Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0};
bc = {u[t, 0] == 0, u[t, 1] == 0, Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 1] == 0};
teqn = LaplaceTransform[{eqn, bc}, t, s] /. Rule @@@ ic
```

Now we have an ODE, solve it with `DSolve`:

```
tsol = u[t, x] /. First@DSolve[teqn/. 
  HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a, u[t, x], x] // Simplify
```

Notice the replacement `HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a` is necessary because `DSolve` has trouble in handling expression containing `LaplaceTransform`. The last step is to transform the solution back, but sadly `InverseLaplaceTransform` can't handle `tsol`. At this point, one work-around is to turn to numeric inverse Laplace transform, you can use [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5026/) or [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/mathsource/4738/) package for this task. But for your specific problem, we can circumvent the issue by expanding `tsol` with Fourier sine series:

```
easyFourierSinCoefficient[expr_, t_, {a_, b_}, n_] := 
 FourierSinCoefficient[expr /. t -> t + a, t, n, 
   FourierParameters -> {1, Pi/(b - a)}] /. t -> t - a

easyTerm[t_, {a_, b_}, n_] := Sin[Pi/(b - a) n (t - a)]

term = easyTerm[x, {0, 1}, n];

coe = easyFourierSinCoefficient[tsol, x, {0, 1}, n]
```

> $$-\left(i\left(\frac{(1+i) (-1)^n e^{i \sqrt{2} \sqrt{s}}}{(1+i) \pi  n+i \sqrt{2} \sqrt{s}}\right.\right....$$

`coe` still looks complex, but inspired by those `(-1)^n`s in it, we split it to odd and even part and simplify:

```
oddcoe = 
 Simplify[coe /. n -> 2 m - 1, m > 0 && m ∈ Integers] /. m -> (1 + n)/2
(* (8 s)/(n^3 π^3 (n^4 π^4 + s^2)) *)

evencoe = Simplify[coe /. n -> 2 m, m ∈ Integers] /. m -> n/2
(* 0 *)
```

`InverseLaplaceTransform` can handle the series form of the transformed solution without difficulty:

```
soloddterm = Function[n, #] &@InverseLaplaceTransform[oddcoe term, s, t]
(* Function[n, (8 Cos[n^2 π^2 t] Sin[n π x])/(n^3 π^3)] *)
```

To find the final solution, just summate:

```
solgenerator[n_] := Compile[{t, x}, #] &@Total@soloddterm@Range[1, n, 2];

sol = solgenerator[200];

Animate[Plot[sol[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> .3], {t, 0, 1}]
```

The animation is similar to the one in the subsequent solution so I'd like to omit it.

---

## Fully `NDSolve`-based Numeric Solution

Go back to the old-fashioned `"TensorProductGrid"`, set `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}` (or `NDSolve` will set `"ScaleFactor"` to `0` so the inconsistent b.c.s will be severely ignored, for more information, check [the obscure tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1306392612)) and `DifferenceOrder -> 2`:

```
mol[n_Integer, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
mol[tf:False|True,sf_:Automatic]:={"MethodOfLines",
"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"->{tf,"ScaleFactor"->sf}}

tu = NDSolveValue[{eqn, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> Union[mol[27, 2], mol[True, 100], {Method -> StiffnessSwitching}], MaxSteps -> Infinity];

Animate[Plot[tu[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> .3], {t, 0, 10}]
```

`NDSolve` spits out the `NDSolveValue::eerr` warning, but in many cases `NDSolveValue::eerr` isn't a big deal, and the result indeed looks OK:

[image]

> **Remark**
>
> 1. The `{Method -> StiffnessSwitching}` option is not necessary in *v9*, but becomes necessary to obtain a reasonable solution at least since
>    *v12.3*.
> 2. The performance of this approach backslides severely at least since *v12.3*. For `{t, 0, 2}`, the timing is about 16 seconds in *v9*, but about 275 seconds in
>    *v12.3*. I haven't found out the reason so far, but the posteriori error estimation is `604.34` in *v12.3*, which is smaller than the `1802.02`
>    in *v9.0.1*.

---

## Partly `NDSolve`-based Numeric Solution

Theoretically we can also set `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> False` to avoid the inconsistent b.c.s being ignored, but strangely `NDSolve` spits out the `icfail` warning and fails. I'm not sure about reason, but found that we can manually discretize the spatial derivative and solve the obtained ODE set with `NDSolve` to avoid the issue.

First, let's define a function `pdetoode` that discretizes PDEs to ODEs (Additionally, though not related to OP's problem, I've also define a function `pdetoae` that discretizes differential equations to algebraic equations based on `pdetoode`. A `diffbc` function is defined to transform b.c. to (almost) equivalent ODE, in certain cases you may need it to avoid the fragile DAE solver of `NDSolve`. A `rebuild` function is also created to combine the list of `InterpolatingFunction`s to a single `InterpolatingFunction`):

```
Clear[fdd, pdetoode, tooderule, pdetoae, diffbc, rebuild]
fdd[{}, grid_, value_, order_, periodic_] := value;
fdd[a__] := NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative@a;

pdetoode[funcvalue_List, rest__] := 
  pdetoode[(Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcvalue) @@ funcvalue[[1]], rest];
pdetoode[{func__}[var__], rest__] := pdetoode[Alternatives[func][var], rest];
pdetoode[front__, grid_?VectorQ, o_Integer, periodic_: False] := 
  pdetoode[front, {grid}, o, periodic];

pdetoode[func_[var__], time_, {grid : {__} ..}, o_Integer, 
   periodic : True | False | {(True | False) ..} : False] := 
  With[{pos = Position[{var}, time][[1, 1]]},
   With[{bound = #[[{1, -1}]] & /@ {grid}, pat = Repeated[_, {pos - 1}], 
     spacevar = Alternatives @@ Delete[{var}, pos]}, 
    With[{coordtoindex = 
       Function[coord, 
         MapThread[Piecewise[{{1, PossibleZeroQ[# - #2[[1]]]}, 
                              {-1, PossibleZeroQ[# - #2[[-1]]]}}, All] &, {coord, bound}]]},
     tooderule@Flatten@{
        ((u : func) | Derivative[dx1 : pat, dt_, dx2___][(u : func)])[x1 : pat, t_, 
          x2___] :> (Sow@coordtoindex@{x1, x2}; 
          fdd[{dx1, dx2}, {grid}, Outer[Derivative[dt][u@##]@t &, grid], 
           "DifferenceOrder" -> o, PeriodicInterpolation -> periodic]), 
        inde : spacevar :> 
         With[{i = Position[spacevar, inde][[1, 1]]}, Outer[Slot@i &, grid]]}]]];

tooderule[rule_][pde_List] := tooderule[rule] /@ pde;
tooderule[rule_]@Equal[a_, b_] := 
  Equal[tooderule[rule][a - b], 0] //. eqn : HoldPattern@Equal[_, _] :> Thread@eqn;
tooderule[rule_][expr_] := #[[Sequence @@ #2[[1, 1]]]] & @@ Reap[expr /. rule]

pdetoae[funcvalue_List, rest__] := 
  pdetoae[(Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcvalue) @@ funcvalue[[1]], rest];
pdetoae[{func__}[var__], rest__] := pdetoae[Alternatives[func][var], rest];

pdetoae[func_[var__], rest__] := 
 Module[{t}, 
  Function[pde, #[
       pde /. {Derivative[d__][u : func][inde__] :> 
          Derivative[d, 0][u][inde, t], (u : func)[inde__] :> u[inde, t]}] /. (u : func)[
         i__][t] :> u[i]] &@pdetoode[func[var, t], t, rest]]

diffbc[rst__][a : _List | _Equal] := diffbc[rst] /@ a
diffbc[dvar : {t_, order_} | (t_) .., sf_: 0][a_] /; sf =!= t := sf a + D[a, dvar]

rebuild[funcarray_, grid_?VectorQ, timeposition_: 1] := 
 rebuild[funcarray, {grid}, timeposition]

rebuild[funcarray_, grid_, timeposition_?Negative] := 
 rebuild[funcarray, grid, Range[Length@grid + 1][[timeposition]]]

rebuild[funcarray_, grid_, timeposition_: 1] /; Dimensions@funcarray === Length /@ grid :=
  With[{depth = Length@grid}, 
  ListInterpolation[
     Transpose[Map[Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] &, #, {depth}], 
      Append[Delete[Range[depth + 1], timeposition], timeposition]], 
     Insert[grid, Flatten[#][[1]]["Coordinates"][[1]], timeposition]] &@funcarray]
```

The syntax of `pdetoode` is as follows: 1st argument is the function to be discretized (which can be a list i.e. `pdetoode` can handle PDE system), 2nd argument is the independent variable in the resulting ODE system (usually it's the variable playing the role of "time" in the underlying model), 3rd argument is the list of spatial grid, 4th argument is difference order, 5th argument is to determine whether periodic b.c. should be set or not. (5th argument is optional, the default setting is `False`. )

Notice `pdetoode` is a general purpose function. You may feel some part of the source code confusing. To understand it, just notice the following truth:

1. `a /. a | b[m_] :> {m}` outputs `{}`.
2. `Derivative[][u]` outputs `u`.

Then discretize `eqn`, `ic` and `bc` and remove redundant equations:

```
lb = 0; rb = 1;

(* Difference order of x: *)
xdifforder = 2;

points = 25;
grid = Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}];

(* There're 4 b.c.s, so we need to remove 4 equations from every PDE/i.c.,
   usually the difference equations that are the "closest" ones to the b.c.s 
   are to be removed: *)
removeredundant = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;
(* Use pdetoode to generate a "function" that discretizes the spatial derivatives of 
   PDE(s) and corresponding i.c.(s) and b.c.(s): *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[u[t, x], t, grid, xdifforder];

odeqn = eqn // ptoofunc // removeredundant;
odeic = removeredundant/@ptoofunc@ic;
odebc = bc // ptoofunc;

sollst = NDSolveValue[{odebc, odeic, odeqn}, u /@ grid, {t, 0, 10}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
(* Rebuild the solution for the PDE from the solution for the ODE set: *)
sol = rebuild[sollst, grid];

Animate[Plot[sol[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> .3], {t, 0, 10}]
```

The animation is similar to the one in the aforementioned solution so I'd like to omit it. This approach seems to be more robust than the fully `NDSolve`-based one, because even if the `xordereqn` i.e. the difference order for spatial derivative is set to `4`,  it's still stable, while the fully `NDSolve`-based one becomes wild when `t` is large.

Comment: Thank you for this. It works but I get different values to you with non physical displacements of about 20 maximum which is larger than the maximum starting displacement ( 0.25). So there is something suspect. I am using version 11. The tutorial is something to read in detail thanks.

Comment: @hugh I tested the code on Wolfram Cloud and got the same result as in v9: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ppP43.png

Comment: @Hugh I just noticed that "ScaleFactor"->1 is still too small, see my update, now the solution should be reasonable.  I've also added an analytic solution to my answer.

Comment: This is excellent work -thank you. The analytic solution is always tricky since there are two branch cuts to be avoided. This is a minimum working example. The problem is how to extend this to more complex problems. I hope you don't mind if I add a more complicated version...

Comment: @Hugh I've added a third solution. If you found the current problem is over-simplified, just add the more complicated one, still, it should be a minimal working example, of course :) .

Comment: How important is it to have the initial displacement compatible with the boundary conditions? I guess I could make this happen by adjusting the gradients of the initial displacement at the beam ends. The initial displacement was more to provide a minimal working example rather than an essential part of the problem.

Comment: @Hugh I should say I don't know. There's no doubt that the document hopes us to keep i.c. and b.c. consistent, but it seems not to give any concrete example for inconsistent i.c. and b.c. causing trouble. "The inconsistent b.c. will be severely ignored" is the only issue I know, and now it's resolved by the `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}` option. Given the difficulty to make i.c. and b.c. consistent in some cases, personally I tend to just live with the warning.

Comment: @xzczd, how can we solve 4th order pde in MMA in 2D/3D? if not mixed formulation!

Comment: @ABCDEMMM That really depends. Please consider asking a separate question with specific example.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for keeping this uptodate. It seems to be a problem of continued interest.

Comment: That's a great answer.

Comment: Glad to see you are still looking at this. I do have a need to go further and look at beams with non-uniform cross sections and a travelling load.

Comment: @xzczd this is a great answer! May I ask a general question: how can I use a piecewise function as an initial condition properly? For example, for a pde with 1st-order derivative w.r.t time, when I use `ic={u[t, x] == Piecewise[{{1/10, x > 1/2}, {2 (1 - x^2) + 1/10, x < 1/2}}]} /. t -> 0`, it always gives an error: Initial condition \[Piecewise]<<1>> is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers. >> Thank you in advance!

Comment: @jsxs `pdetoode`/`pdetoae` assumes the functions in differential equations and i.c./b.c. are `Listable`, in your case the easiest solution is to use `Simplify\`PWToUnitStep` to transform the `Piecewise` to `UnitStep`, example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269796/1871

Answer (score 11):

**Update**:

I have answered a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/185530/18437).

---

Here are two (partial) ideas:

One could try to make use of the `TensorProductGrid` as a discretization method.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := x (1 - x)

tu = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 4}] == 0, 
    u[0, x] == f[x], Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0,
    u[t, 0] == 0, u[t, 1] == 0
    (*,
    Derivative[0,2][u][t,0]\[Equal]0,
    Derivative[0,2][u][t,1]\[Equal]0
    *)
    }, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> "MethodOfLines"}];
```

`DirichletCondition` will trigger a FEM attempt, which does not work as the FEM can not handle 4th order spatial derivatives (V11). Note that I disabled the derivatives as that gave inconsistent initial and boundary conditions. Perhaps you know what needs to be done.

The second idea is to treat this as a pure spatial problem.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := x (1 - x)

tu = NDSolveValue[{
    D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] + D[m[t, x], {x, 2}] == 0,
    D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] == m[t, x],
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == f[x], t == 0],
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 0, x == 1 || x == 0],
    DirichletCondition[m[t, x] == 0, True]}, {u, m}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0,
     1}, Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}];
```

The issue with your decoupling of the equations is that the second equation is no longer time dependent. So I was thinking of making this a purely spatial problem. Have a look and see if the solutions are any good. Maybe the `DirichletCondition` on `m` does not need to be `True` but something more specific. I did not check. Hope this gives you a starting point.

Comment: Sadly both attempts don't work... `NDSolve` probably ignores the inconsistent b.c. in the first case, and ignores the inconsistent i.c. in the second case…

Comment: @xzczd See the update for the second idea.

Comment: The second idea works thank you. However, I don't understand the initial conditions and boundary conditions. The first DirichletCondition is the initial displacement, the second is a boundary condition for each end, the third is unclear as you suggest. However, there is no initial condition for velocity. Is this assumed to be zero?

Comment: I have continued to look at your second solution. Using `DirichletCondition[m[t, x] == 0, x == 1 || x == 0]` instead of the last boundary condition gives a different solution.  Also, how would I implement an initial condition with zero displacement and an initial velocity? Thanks

Comment: I think the amplitude of the solution given by the revised second idea is still incorrect?

Comment: @xzczd, I will not have time to look at this more, perhaps later. Sorry about that. If the answer is too confusing, I can delete it?

Comment: I think it's OK to keep it undeleted, you've claimed it's "a starting point" in the body of answer anyway. Look forward to your complete answer :)

Answer (score 10):

Direct Analytic Solution by Separation of Variables

```
Off[General::wrsym]
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = x (1 - x);

pde = D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 4}] == 0;

    ic = {u[0, x] == f[x], Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0};
    bc = {u[t, 0] == 0, u[t, 1] == 0, Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 1] == 0};
```

Separate variables in the form

```
u[t_, x_] = T[t] X[x]

pde = pde/u[t, x] // Apart 
(* D[T[t],t,t]/T[t]+D[X[x],{x,4}]/X[x]==0 *)
```

The first term depends on t, the other x.  That can only happen if each term
is equal to a constant.  We want sinusoidal in t so that we set

```
teq = D[T[t], t, t]/T[t] == -w^2;

    T[t_] = T[t] /. (DSolve[teq, T[t], t][[1]]) /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}
(* c1 Cos[t w]+c2 Sin[t w] *)

From ic[[2]], we can eliminate c2 right away

c2 = c2 /. Solve[ic[[2]], c2][[1]]
(* 0 *)
```

The x equation

```
 xsol = ((DSolve[pde, X[x], x] // Flatten) /. {C[1] -> c3, C[2] -> c4, 
      C[3] -> c5, C[4] -> c6}) // ExpToTrig // Simplify

    (* {X[x]->c3 Cos[Sqrt[w] x]+(c6-c4) Sinh[Sqrt[w] x]+(c4+c6)
Cosh[Sqrt[w] x]+c5 Sin[Sqrt[w] x]} *)

X[x_] = X[x] /. % /. {c6 - c4 -> c4, c4 + c6 -> c6};

u[t,x]
 (* c1 Cos[t w] (c3 Cos[Sqrt[w] x]+c4 Sinh[Sqrt[w] x]+c5 Sin[Sqrt[w]
x]+c6 Cosh[Sqrt[w] x]) *)

bc[[1]]
(* c1 (c3+c6) Cos[t w]==0 *)
```

From which

```
c6 = -c3;
```

And to consolidate constants

```
c1 = 1;
```

Now

```
bc[[3]]
(* -2 c3 w Cos[t w]==0 *)
```

From which

```
c3 = 0;

bc[[2]]
(* Cos[t w] (c4 Sinh[Sqrt[w]]+c5 Sin[Sqrt[w]])==0 *)

c4 = c4 /. Solve[bc[[2]], c4][[1]]
(* -c5 Sin[Sqrt[w]] Csch[Sqrt[w]] *)

 bc[[4]]
(* -2 c5 w Sin[Sqrt[w]] Cos[t w]==0 *)
```

Instead of solving for the trivial c5 = 0 solution, we will solve for w.

```
Reduce[ {Sin[Sqrt[w]] == 0, w > 0}, w]  

 (*C[1]\[Element]Integers&&((C[1]>=1&&w\[Equal]4 \[Pi]^2 \
C[1]^2)||(C[1]>=0&&w==4 \[Pi]^2 C[1]^2+4 \[Pi]^2 C[1]+\[Pi]^2))*)
```

All boils down to

```
w = n^2 Pi^2;

$Assumptions = n \[Element] Integers && n > 0;

u[t_, x_] = u[t, x] // Simplify
(* c5 Cos[Pi^2 n^2 t] Sin[PI n x] *)

(ic[[1, 1]] // Simplify) == ic[[1, 2]]
(* c5 Sin[Pi n x]==(1-x) x *)
```

We use orthogonality to solve for c5.  Multiply each side of the above
by `Sin[n Pi x]` and Integrate over the length of the beam

```
    Integrate[%[[1]] Sin[n Pi x], {x, 0, 1}] == 
  Integrate[%[[2]] Sin[n Pi x], {x, 0, 1}] // Simplify
(* Pi^3 c5 n^3+4 (-1)^n==4 *)

c5 = c5 /. Solve[%, c5][[1]] // Simplify
(* -((4 ((-1)^n-1))/(Pi^3 n^3)) *)

u[t, x]
(* -((4 ((-1)^n-1) Cos[Pi^2 n^2 t] Sin[Pi n x])/(Pi^3 n^3))*)
```

We can see that `(-1)^n-1` will make all even n terms equal to 0.
Rather than just choosing odd terms in the series for u, we can change
n to 2m-1, which will give us only the odd n terms.

```
    um[t_, x_] = ((u[t, x] /. n -> 2 m - 1) // 
   Simplify[#, m > 0 && m \[Element] Integers] &) 
(* (8 Cos[Pi^2 (1-2 m)^2 t] Sin[Pi (2 m-1) x])/(Pi^3 (2 m-1)^3) *)
```

The analytic solution is

```
 u[t_, x_] := 
 8/Pi^3 Sum[(
   Cos[Pi^2 (1 - 2 m)^2 t] Sin[Pi (2 m - 1) x])/(2 m - 1)^3, {m,  1, \[Infinity]}]
```

which is not practical for computing.  Similar to the method of xzczd above:

```
term = Function[m, #] &@um[t, x]      

 (* Function[m,(8 Cos[Pi^2 (1-2 m)^2 t] Sin[Pi (2 m-1) x])/(Pi^3 (2 m-1)^3)]*)

mterms[m_] := Compile[{t, x}, #] &@Total@term@Range[1, m]

U = mterms[100];

Animate[Plot[U[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> .3], {t, 0, 1}]
```

We get the same plot as the Laplace Transform solution.

Comment: Thank you. This needs to be here as the classic text book solution of the equation.  I agree that this is simpler than going into Laplace transforms. Unfortunately it only works for uniform beams. I don't think we can use this for beams where the mass or stiffness varies along the length. This is why I was hoping to use the finite element method. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The analytical solution of E-B beam after assuming harmonic dependency,

```
    L = 1;
sol = Flatten[DSolve[(D[y[x], {x, 4}] - b^4 y[x]) == 0, y[x], x]];
a = y[x] /. sol;
beamsol = Simplify[ExpToTrig[a]];
(*below is the text book form general sol*)
generalsol = 
  Flatten[beamsol /. {C[1] -> C1, (C[2] + C[4]) -> C2, 
     C[3] -> C3, (C[4] - C[2]) -> C4}];
(*BC*)
e[1] = beamsol /. x -> 0;
e[2] = D[beamsol, {x, 2}] /. x -> 0;
e[3] = beamsol /. x -> L;
e[4] = D[beamsol, {x, 2}] /. x -> L;
eq = Table[e[i], {i, 1, 4}];
var = Table[C[i], {i, 1, 4}];
R = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];
MatrixForm[R];
P = Det[R];
s1 = NSolve[P == 0 && 0 < b < 10];
s2 = b /. s1;
NN = Flatten[NullSpace[R /. b -> s2[[1]]]];
beamsol = (beamsol /. 
     Table[var[[i]] -> NN[[i]], {i, 1, Length[NN]}]) /. b -> s2[[1]];
Plot[beamsol, {x, 0, L}]
```

Comment: This isn't what OP wants, is it?

Comment: Thank you this is the standard solution for harmonic motion. However, I want a solution from initial conditions. This could be built-up from a Fourier series of your solutions. However, I really wish to be general and be able to solve non-uniform beams for general initial conditions.